# How to automatically reload a screen(form) after a given period of inactivity in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How can I automatically reload a screen(form), if there have been no activity on the page for a given period of time? in codenameone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITimer can be used to schedule tasks.

```
    UITimer timer = new UITimer(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        ...
        }
    });
    timer.schedule(1000, false, Display.getInstance().getCurrent());
```

Comment: thanks.it worked.but i want to set text to textfileld on specific time interval.when i does settext to textfield it gives error